# yii2 map extension showing "MissingKeyMapError"

Tags: google-maps, yii2

I have install extension from http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-latlon-finder/

but is showing me error message "MissingKeyMapError"

I have API key but not sure where to put this.

please help me for same

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, this project is last updated 2 years ago, so it can be outdated with current API's.

As a solution, i can suggest you to use [2amigos - Google Maps](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library) extension. It's pretty simple with good documentation.

After installing it, just add this to `main.php` config file:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'dosamigos\google\maps\MapAsset' => [
                'options' => [
                    'key' => 'this_is_my_key',
                    'language' => 'id',
                    'version' => '3.1.18'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
],
```

Just replace `this_is_my_key` with your key.

The bad thing in this solution is that you will have to write some additional code to handle user input of lat/long and display it on 2amigos map.